# Granger Causality & Impulse Response Function

Tags: granger-causality, impulse-response

How does an Impulse Response function relate to Granger causality?

Is it not basically a visualization of what we measure with Granger causality? (see http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html)

Comment: It's a pity nobody has answered this. Have you found the answer yourself yet?

Comment: @RichardHardy this seems to shed some light on this question: http://monde.cirano.qc.ca/~dufourj/Web_Site/Dufour_Tessier_1993_EL_ImpulseResponseAnalysis.pdf

Comment: @lucasfariaslf, the title looks very relevant indeed. Thanks for sharing!